How to share data between two different processes in Linux?
On my Ubuntu 22.04 I have the following situation:

ROS2 is installed system-wide and not in an environment
PyTorch is installed in its virtual environment

My concept look likes the following schema:

In a ROS node two values (floats) are collected over a topic
The two values are sent to the second process, which runs in a virtual environment
The process in the virtual environment process the data and send an answer to the first process (the ROS node)
The ROS node process this last information and the loop restart again and again.

I found a nice library for Python and realize a minimal example without using ROS:
# This should be the ROS node
import time
import SharedArray as shared_mem

query = shared_mem.create("shm://query", 2)
request = shared_mem.create("shm://request", 1)

i, j = 0, 0

try:
    while True:

        query[0], query[1] = i, j
        i += 1
        j -= 1

        time.sleep(2)
        print(f"i: {i}, j: {j}")

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    del query
    del request

and this the "receiver" that processes the data and send a value back:
import time
import SharedArray as shared_mem
# import torch
# import torch.nn as nn

gt = shared_mem.attach("shm://query")
st = shared_mem.attach("shm://request")

k = 0

try:
    while True:

        if gt.size == 2:
            print(f"{gt[0]}, {gt[1]}")
            st[k] += 2

        else:
            print("Empty")

        k += 1

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

Running this code I realize, that I have two problems:

I cannot synchronize the receiver with the sender. The sender should wait the answer from the receiver before going further.
Without a lock somewhere I run into a race condition.

Any ideas?

For some ROS2 version/platform, you could try call_async() and spin_until_future_complete() to achieve synchronous communication. Here is foxy example. This article might be also worth checking.
In the pure Python world, there seems to be several other ways. You could use Process, pipe, socket for synchronous communication (i.e., sender wait for the answer). Python community may better help you than the ROS2 community.
To protect shared memory, you can to use lock or other mutual exclusion. Just be careful not to make a deadlock.
Hope this helps!

At the end I used unix sockets. Anyway I accept your answer since, you mentioned them

Great! Have a good one.
